# What component of the stress–energy tensor contains the kinetic energy of heat?

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

As I understand it, the component $T_{00}$ of the stress-energy tensor contains the energy density (which equals the mass density), $T_{0i}$ are the impulse flows (intuitively speaking, the velocities), and $T_{ii}$ (the diagonals of the stress tensor) are the pressures in the respective directions.

In which of these components 'goes' the kinetic energy of the matter's heat?

On a microscopic level, heat is just motion, so I suppose it should be in $T_{0i}$.

However, if you look at the sun as one homogeneous body like in a Schwarzschild solution, I'm not sure where to put it.

- Is it just energy, so it's part of $T_{00}$? This would mean that $T_{00}$ does not equal the mass density.
- Or is it part of the pressure, thus going to $T_{ii}$?

Comment: Hi Bastian. Have a look at my answer to the duplicate Kyle suggested. Hopefully it should be obvious that random thermal motion contributes to the diagonal elements (excluding $T_{00}$). If you think it isn't obvious comment here and I can reopen this question.

Comment: Thanks John! It's obvious now. Somehow I thought $T_ii$ is a directed 3-vector that represents some flow, but if it stands for an undirected pressure, then it's clear that thermal energy is part of it.